# Unable to send message to websocket from another service

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs, spring-messaging

I followed the tutorial [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) to setup websockets within my web application, and below is the resultant code. Now I thought if I write to the topic from another class (`LocationManagerImpl.java`) in my application, I would be able to send the message to all the clients who are subscribed to the topic. But, it seems the client isn't getting the message. If I debug and also check the logs, I get indications that my message has been written to the topic, but it isn't being read by the client.
I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Please help.

*HelloController.java*

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public HelloResponse hello(HelloRequest request) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        HelloResponse response = new HelloResponse();
        response.setContent(request.getContent() + " ... appending response");
        return response;
    }
}
```

*WebSocketConfiguration.java*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
    } 
}
```

*hello.js*

```
var stompClient = null;

function setConnected(connected) {
    document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
    document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
    document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
}

function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/aegis/hello');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
    });
}

function disconnect() {
    if (stompClient != null) {
        stompClient.disconnect();
    }
    setConnected(false);
    console.log("Disconnected");
}

function sendName() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'content': name }));
}

function showGreeting(message) {
    var response = document.getElementById('response');
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    response.appendChild(p);
}
```

*sample.jsp*

```
<%@ include file="/common/taglibs.jsp"%>

<head>
    <title><fmt:message key="sample.title"/></title>
    <meta name="menu" content="SampleMenu"/>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/0.3.4/sockjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/stomp.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/hello.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            disconnect();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<noscript><h2 style="color: #ff0000">Seems your browser doesn't support Javascript! Websocket relies on Javascript being enabled. Please enable
    Javascript and reload this page!</h2></noscript>
<div>
    <div>
        <button id="connect" onclick="connect();">Connect</button>
        <button id="disconnect" disabled="disabled" onclick="disconnect();">Disconnect</button>
    </div>
    <div id="conversationDiv">
        <label>What is your name?</label><input type="text" id="name" />
        <button id="sendName" onclick="sendName();">Send</button>
        <p id="response"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

*LocationManagerImpl.java*

```
@Service("locationManager")
public class LocationManagerImpl extends GenericManagerImpl<TripTrack,Long> implements LocationManager {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

        @Override
        public Response locations(JsonRequest loc) {

            //... some code here     

            // Send to UI
            messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", "{\"content\": \"hello\"}");

            //... some more code here
        }
}
```